# Scheme procedure to substitute the element in a pair

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to write a procedure: when a pair starts with a, it would return b; when a pair starts with b, it would return c; and when a pair starts with c, it would return a.

```
 (define e '((a b) (b c) (c a)))

(define (make-encoder e)
    (cond ((eq? 'a (car (assq 'a e)))
        (cadr (assq 'a e)))
          ((eq? 'b (car (assq 'b e)))
        (cadr (assq 'b e)))
          ((eq? 'c (car (assq 'c e)))
        (cadr (assq 'c e)))))
```

What is returned is only 'b', so I'm wondering where my brackets are wrong in cutting off the remaining code? I have played around for so long and wondering if that's my problem, or if it something else.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want the procedure to do. Can you give a few examples of the desired behavior?

Comment: @BrendanCannell Sorry, my end goal is to call upon a list for example '(a b a c a b)), and for it to return (b c b a b c). So every a is being replaced by b, every b for c, and every c for a.

Comment: It sometimes helps to read code out loud. "To make an encoder from the list `e`: if the key for `a` in `e` is `a`, return the value for `a` in `e`; otherwise, if the key for `b` in `e` is `b`,..." doesn't sound right. (Look up "rubber duck debugging".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's an issue of wrong parens; I can't really see a way to tweak your code to get the desired behavior. Here's how I would do it:

```
(define (make-encoder assoc-list)
  (lambda (lst)
    (define (-> elem)
      (cadr (assq elem assoc-list)))
    (map -> lst)))
```

As you can see, when you call this procedure with an association list such as `e`, it will return a new function that takes a list and maps `->` over it, where `->` looks up the element in the association list and returns result. Hence:

```
> ((make-encoder e) '(a b a c a b))
'(b c b a b c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have looking up the value of a key in a association list with `(cadr (assq k a))` but what you are missing is how to apply that to every item in a list. That is where `map` comes in. So:

```
> (map (lambda (v) (cadr (assq v '((a b) (b c) (c a))))) '(a b a c a b))
'(b c b a b c)
```

This can be turned into a function by placing it within lambdas or a definition  and replacing the values with bound names.